# how can I determine if SP1 has been applied to our TFS 2008 install

Tags: tfs

I don't want to download and install SP1 for Team Foundation server 2008 if I don't need to.  But I'm not sure how to determine what version our server is currently running?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have Visual Studio Team Explorer 2008 SP1 installed on your client machine, then look in source control explorer to see if you have anything populated in the Last Check-in Date column.  If there is data the server is SP1, if there isn't then it is pre TFS2008 SP1. (See my [blog post](http://www.woodwardweb.com/teamprise/000436.html) where I talk about this feature)

Alternatively if you can log into the machine, take a look at ProgramFiles\Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Team Foundation Server\Web Services\Services\bin\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.dll.  SP1 has a version of 9.0.30428.1

Answer (score 1):

[This tool](http://devmatter.blogspot.com/2008/10/tfsinfo-updated-for-tfs-2008-sp1.html) looks like it could do the job.